# Fetching the automatically generated id from cloud firestore

Tags: angular

I fetched my data from the cloud firestore in my angular component as shown in the code below

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 
{AngularFirestoreDocument,AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreCollection} 
from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemsService {
itemscollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<any>
items:Observable<any[]>

constructor(public afs:AngularFirestore,db:AngularFirestore) { 


}

getitems(){

  return   

this.items=this.afs.collection('categories',ref=>ref.orderBy('name'))
.valueChanges()  

}

}
```

.component.ts file

```
export class AdminNewComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('f') form:NgForm
categories
default="Bread"
constructor(public iservice:ItemsService,private 
prservice:ProductsService,private router:Router,private 
route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(items=>{
  this.categories=items
  // console.log(this.categories)

})
}
```

and then i render it into the html component
but the problem i have is how do i retreive all the automatically generated id from database like shown here in the screenshot below

**https://ibb.co/fp3MBF0**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of valueChanges(), use snapshotChanges(). It would look something like this...

export const mapFireBaseListResponse = (list: AngularFireList) =>

```
list.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(items => 
        items.map(item => ({
                key: item.payload.key, 
                ...item.payload.val()
            })
        )
    )
);
```